# Oracle to PostgreSQL Migration Changed Data Capture

Tags: postgresql, oracle

We are currently migrating our application back end from Oracle to Postgres and my concern/query is that in case we face issues post migration, in a worst case scenario we may need to revert back to Oracle until the same is fixed to avoid major downtime. For that I want to take only the changed/modified data and then restore the same on Oracle.

I was looking into CDC tools like Debezium, but since I have HA Patroni+PostgreSQL (physical replication) already in place I'm not sure whether CDC could help me with my requirement.

Looking for some suggestions and inputs on how to perform this operation.